# Which people know account's password?

Tags: passwords, web

i have heard lately by some "friends" that they can access anything on the web(accounts, passwords) without hacking techniques. Apart from ISPs and propably services like google(gmail etc) who else can have access to accounts and passwords? Is this possible without cracking software, keyloggers, phising etc?

Answer (score 2):

"Hacking" is a relative term.

In terms passwords, accounts, and "hacking", I'm going to talk about security, because that's what these items are related to.

"Security" is a relative term.

It sounds like you don't know much about security, so I'm going to keep things simple; if you have a device or service available to people, it's already got security problems.  It's just a matter of how much effort someone's willing to put in to breach those that security.

In short, yes, someone can bypass usernames and password security pretty simply; especially if the username and password they're using was written down on a piece of paper and taped to the bottom of a someone's keyboard.  Technically speaking, no "hacking" was involved, no effort beyond lifting someone's keyboard off the table.  Even using social engineering, you could coax someone to giving up their username and passwords, both blatantly and subversively (there's a great Psych episode, Season 1 Episode 11, "He Loves Me, He Loves Me Not, He Loves Me, Oops He's Dead", where Shawn and Gus infiltrate a speed dating ring to find a couple of murders who use the speed dating as an identity theft ploy that outlines how easy it is to get unique information that can be used to access someone's bank account to reset their passwords and drain their accounts).

As a note, not all ISPs or application services purposely store passwords in a form that's easy to crack.  Some do, because they're lazy and run by incompetent people, but not all.  That being said, usernames are everywhere.  Your username; my username, lots of people's usernames are available right now, even on this page.

The point is, you need to train yourself to be more aware of what is a security risk and what are you putting out there for other people to see.  In most cases, if you use practical security measures, you'll be fine.  Just remember that you're in control of most of what you make available, and if you don't want someone to find it, then don't make it available.